# How to Export Category URLS

Tags: magento-1.9, category, url, importexport, export

I have started to change over all my product URL from my old website to my new so we do not lose any google ratings, however i can't see any option to export category urls, only products or customers?

What i am trying to do is export a CSV which contain my categories and all of their URLs like you can do with the products, as i need to change the URLs to match our old website as we do not want to lose our google ratings. Then once I have changed them in the CSV file then i need to import the file again.

I have checked the export system in Magento but can only find a way of exporting customer or products.

Answer (score 3):

So there are a few things that you can to get your results with a variety of effort levels. As I see it the two "real" solutions here would be.

1. Build your own category export/import system,
2. Import old pages and create url redirects for them,

Firstly a quick touch on point 1. You can always use something like [FastSimpleImport](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport)
or any other third party import system to build your own import/export for categories.

From my opinion this is the wrong way to go about it. I would consider creating the url redirects inside Magento this can be done via the admin, which could be a long job, or your could create a stand-a-lone script or module set-up script to do this for you.

For this your would simply need a mapping from old to new, loop through this mapping and create your rewrites.

Sure both solutions require coding but for me the second option might seem a bit "easier".

Answer (score 0):

You can get all of your categories from the sitemap. Just generate a fresh one if your sitemap.xml file is out of date. There will be a list of categories in there - albeit in XML format. You can probably fix that with a little bit of time in a text editor search/replacing tags or, if you have more categories, doing something to parse the file properly.

Comment: But i need a way of importing the data once i have changed the urls

Comment: I think you need to explain in more depth what it is that you are trying to achieve and the steps taken so far.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: You could design your new catalog to have the same URL structure as before or you could just run some 302 redirects on your site to pick up old urls and redirect them to their new home. This second approach is what most people do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Module For Category Import and Export. This Module help to you export and import Category

http://www.magentoworks.net/importexport-magento-category-extension

This one may be helpfull for you